# Confusion over Python versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, apple-m1

[image: Python versions]

I am confused about setting up the Python environment on Mac M1. I have been using the latest version of Python3 3.10.4. However when I issue the following command at the Terminal. python3 --version. I get Python 3.9.12 why? I would like to set the latest version as default and be able to install packages like numpy and matplotlib for it. Ideally I would like to get rid of all the other versions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is *your responsibility* to keep these things organized. It looks live you've installed different interpreters in various different ways. My suggestion would be to pick something like `conda` to manage your Python environments and stick with that. If you want to "get rid of all the other versions" you are going to have to remove them, but how are we supposed to know how you've installed everything?

Answer (score 4):

When you type a command like `python` in the Terminal, without specifying the full path to the `python` executable, the shell (normally `zsh` on macOS) searches in multiple places to try to find a program called `python`.

The places that are searched are specified by the `PATH` environment variable, which is a list of directories separated by `:`.

For example, with the following `PATH` settings, it would try `/opt/homebrew/bin/python` first, then `/usr/local/bin/python`, then `/usr/bin/python`, etc. until it finds it. The first one wins.

```
% echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When you activate Conda environments and other Python virtual environments, these temporarily modify the `PATH` during that session, so that the programs installed in these environments take priority over the system ones.

To figure out *which* Python would be started, you can use the `which` command, or `command -v`:

```
% which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
% command -v python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
```

Finally you can ask Python directly where it is running from:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
```

---

You appear to have many Pythons installed in many places which is creating your confusion. You say you have been using 3.10.4 which is the one at `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

If you want to install packages on this Python, you can specify its path explicitly:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. Juste recently start using Python and Mac, I usually use R on Windows. I do think there are improvements to be made in the whole Python eco systems. If you use R and RStudio you dont have to worry about all of this OS organization efforts, just focus on the Data Science. This is part of the reason for Anaconda for Python. I think something smaller a lighter should come along so users of Python would focus on programing or Data Science and not on OS organization.